# Java - File Reading after exporting to executable jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-io

In eclipse when I export to my code to an executable jar file, the jar can't find any files. The code I'm using is
`FileReader fr = new FileReader("src/pkg/Password.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);`
That is generating a `FileNotFoundException`
Note: this code works fine in eclipse.
Is there a way to do this properly without using `.getResource()` or `.getResourseAsStream()` because there is no constructor for FileReader with a URL or an InputStream

Here is my code for one class:

```
package pkg;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;

public class MainP extends JPanel {

/**
 * 
 */
private JButton btnAddCoupon, btnChangeStarCount;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2669362135801409216L;
private JPasswordField passwordField;
static String s;

/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public MainP() {
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[] { 245, 94, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[] { 49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE };
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[] { 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
            Double.MIN_VALUE };
    setLayout(gridBagLayout);

            JButton btnCashIn = new JButton("Cash In");
            btnCashIn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    MainClass.f2.setVisible(true);
                    MainClass.f.setVisible(false);

                }
            });
            GridBagConstraints gbc_btnCashIn = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc_btnCashIn.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            gbc_btnCashIn.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 5);
            gbc_btnCashIn.gridx = 0;
            gbc_btnCashIn.gridy = 0;
            add(btnCashIn, gbc_btnCashIn);

    JLabel lblAdminrequiresPassword = new JLabel(
            "Admin (Requires Password)");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblAdminrequiresPassword = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblAdminrequiresPassword.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_lblAdminrequiresPassword.gridx = 9;
    gbc_lblAdminrequiresPassword.gridy = 0;
    add(lblAdminrequiresPassword, gbc_lblAdminrequiresPassword);

    btnAddCoupon = new JButton("Add Coupon");
    btnAddCoupon.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MainClass.f3.setVisible(true);
            MainClass.f.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnAddCoupon = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnAddCoupon.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnAddCoupon.gridx = 9;
    gbc_btnAddCoupon.gridy = 1;
    add(btnAddCoupon, gbc_btnAddCoupon);

    btnChangeStarCount = new JButton("Change Star Count");
    btnChangeStarCount.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            MainClass.f4.setVisible(true);
            MainClass.f.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_btnChangeStarCount = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_btnChangeStarCount.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_btnChangeStarCount.gridx = 9;
    gbc_btnChangeStarCount.gridy = 2;
    add(btnChangeStarCount, gbc_btnChangeStarCount);
    enab(false);
    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    passwordField.setForeground(Color.red);
    passwordField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/pkg/Password.txt"));
                s = br.readLine();
                if (passwordField.getText().equals(s)) {
                    passwordField.setForeground(Color.green);
                    enab(true);
                } else {
                    passwordField.setForeground(Color.red);
                    enab(false);
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/pkg/Password.txt"));
                s = br.readLine();
                if (passwordField.getText().equals(s)) {
                    passwordField.setForeground(Color.green);
                    enab(true);
                } else {
                    passwordField.setForeground(Color.red);
                    enab(false);
                }
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            // XXX Do not change XXX
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_passwordField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_passwordField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_passwordField.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_passwordField.gridx = 9;
    gbc_passwordField.gridy = 3;
    add(passwordField, gbc_passwordField);

    JLabel lblPasswordField = new JLabel("Password Field");

    GridBagConstraints gbc_lblPasswordField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_lblPasswordField.gridx = 9;
    gbc_lblPasswordField.gridy = 4;
    add(lblPasswordField, gbc_lblPasswordField);

}

private void enab(boolean b) {
    btnAddCoupon.setEnabled(b);
    btnChangeStarCount.setEnabled(b);
}

}
```

**Note:** I tried using both `FileReader` and `InputStreamReader`

### Directory Tree:

`MyJar.jar (C://Users/Orion31/Desktop/MyJar.jar
|
---- pkg
      |
      --- Password.txt
      |
      --- StarCount.txt
      |
      --- CS.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Don't ever reference `src` within any path, it won't exist once the program is exported.

All resources are stored as entries within a zip file (the Jar file), which means you can no longer use any file access methods like you are, instead you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourcesStream` instead

> Is there a way to do this properly without using .getResource() or .getResourseAsStream()

No (or at least none I would be happy to discuses)

> because there is no constructor for FileReader with a URL or an InputStream

Actually, there is, or more to the point, there is a way, you can use a `InputStreamReader` instead of a `FileReader`, for example...

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pkg/Password.txt"))) {
    // Read as normal
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll try that.  Is it `InputStreamWriter` for writing to files?

Comment: Nope, it would be `OutputStreamWriter`, but you can't write to resources

Comment: by resources, do you mean you can't write to text files?

Comment: No, I mean those embedded within the Jar file ;)

Comment: what do you mean by embedded?  And also, when using an `OutputStreamWriter` what constructor do I use because both `#getResource` and `#getResourceAsStream` don't work

Comment: When using `InputStreamReaders` `NullPointerExceptions` are thrown

Comment: then I tried `FileReader` again without `src` in the path and `FileNotFoundExceptions` were thrown.

Comment: `getResource` and `getResourceAsStream` will return `null` if the specified resource does not exist at the specified location.  Check that the resource you are trying to load is contained within the Jar file.  A "embedded" resource typically describes a resource which can be located relative to the classpath, in you case, the `Password.txt` exists within the Jar file.  Typically, this means you can't write to them, as they are not "files", but a just a series of bytes within another file (a zip based file in this case)

Comment: So is there a way to write to embedded files?  Also, I'm pretty sure that my files exist because in eclipse, just adding `src` to the path, it works...

Comment: 1- No, you can't write to a file once it's embedded within the Jar file; 2- Yes, in Eclipse it will "appear" to exits, because your execution context is the projects directory, so it can see the `src` path, but once you export the program to a jar file and move the jar file else where, the `src` path will no longer exist

Comment: So is there an alternative way to write to files?  Also, using your tips for reading, I still get a `FileNotFoundException` or a `NullPointerException`...

Comment: 1- Write to disk location; 2- Unzip the jar file, verify that the file exists and it's path is what you expect

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to this whole writing and reading thing, although I've done it once before, it wasn't a huge accomplishment, so this question might sound dumb...  What is a disk location?

Comment: A Jar file, is a Zip file, it contains a bunch of data in prescribed format, which can be searched by Java at runtime to allow you to extract "resources" from it.  Zip files can't be updated (not without a lot of hassle which isn't support by Java for what you seem to be trying to do).  A "disk location" is any disk/folder, local or remote (network), which you can read/write to.

Comment: ok, thanks!  Do you know any good programs that extract/unzip jar file?

Comment: What OS?  Windows Explorer can extract zip files (you might have to change the extension of the file to `.zip`

Comment: @MaProgrammer Ya, I run windows 8.  So, do I need to just change it to .zip or use some kind of program that changes the extension "safely" because changing the name of it (like double clicking and renaming it from MyJar.jar to MyJar.zip) but I don't know if that really shows the right files...

Comment: Using the method of changing a file to a zip mentioned above, I confirmed that the file exists in the path that I thought, so do you have any idea why it throws a `NullPointerException`? Where would the disk location be?  Would it be in the jar or somewhere stored on my computer because I want it to work on any computer without the extra files.

Comment: Based on the information you've provided either `"/pkg/Password.txt"` or `"pkg/Password.txt"` should work.  You can store files anywhere you, that's up to you, I tend to use `user.home` (`System.getProperty("user.home")`) as a base (this is the user's home directory)

Comment: So like in the directory `C://Users/Orion31/Password.txt`?  Also, I will edit the original post with my code so you can see if something is wrong because trying both `FileReader` and `InputStreamReader` with the right directory, it still generates a `NullPointerException`

Comment: You're still trying to read a file named `Password.txt` from the directory `/pkg` (note that this is the root directory of the current drive) - `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/pkg/Password.txt"));`, you need to use `BufferedReader reader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/pkg/Password.txt"))`.  The only reason this returns `null` is the fact that the `/pkg/Password.txt` doesn't exist within the current classpath (including your Jar)

Comment: Yes, I made sure it existed, but it still doesn't work.  In eclipse it also doesn't work, but I can see the tree of files, which says it exists in `pkg`.  I'll try one last time.  Also, is the home directory `C://Users/Orion31/Password.txt`?

Comment: I tried again with `InputStreamReaders` and again recieved `NullPointerExceptions`

Comment: On your case C://Users/Orion31 is your home directory, but it will be different for different users. Post an image of the directory structure of the jar if you can

Comment: Also, `getResource` is case sensitive, so make sure the path and name are EXACTLY correct

Comment: Don't worry, I learned that java is case sensitive the hard(ish) way ;)

Comment: Are you able to share the Jar file (the text file can be empty)?

Comment: So, I download your jar file, linked into a new project (in NetBeans), so the Jar file was within my build and run path and used both `System.out.println(JavaApplication158.class.getResource("/pkg/Password.txt"));` (`JavaApplication158` is my awesome test class) and `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/pkg/Password.txt"));` and both printed out a non-null value

Comment: I tried what you did, and received no errors, but when I use an `InputStreamReader`, it generates a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: What does `JavaApplication158.class.getResourceAsStream("/pkg/Password.txt"))` return?

Comment: It returns nothing, but other lines of code return `NullPointerExceptions`

Comment: Nothing? Do you mean null?

Comment: If `System.out.println(JavaApplication158.class.getResource("/pkg/Password.txt"));` prints a non-null value (a `URL`) then `System.out.println(JavaApplication158.class.getResourceAsStream("/pkg/Password.txt"));` should print a non-null value...

Comment: No, not a nullpointer it just returns nothing at all.  The console is blank except the other nullpointers that link to different lines of code (`MainClass.class.getResource("/pkg/Password.txt");` is on line 20 and none of the null pointers link to line 20.)  When using `System.out.println(MainClass.class.getResource("/pkg/Password.txt"));`It returns the URL, which is in the eclipse workspace.